# Finding coefficients using the Dual Basis

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: 1]

The part I need help with is finding the three coefficients
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Prove that $S^1,S^2,S^3$ are linearly independent in $V^*$ so they form a basis of it. To find the coefficients consider the polynomial $(x-a_1)(x-a_2),(x-a_1)(x-a_3)$ and $(x-a_3)(x-a_2)$.

Comment: thanks for the answer, that part I had no difficulty in. I need help finding, explicitly, the three coefficient

Comment: I edited my answer and I hope that it's useful.